# Strange behaviour in Android M Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

So I have this app that I made before the Android M came out, the app has `permissions` such as `Camera`(using custom camera within the app) `Write & Read` from external storage and `System Alert` `permission` I installed the app to my phone which has android 6.0 and the app was able to run normally and without any restrictions. I was able to use the camera, save files into sdcard & show a custom view using the `WindowManager` API.
please take a note that the target SDK for the app is android lollipop.

**my question:** is this even possible? the OS let apps that has target SDK smaller than M to run perfectly without asking for permissions? and if this is actually the default behaviour that android developers implement?

P.S: the identified question is not really applicable for my question. and i don't see any similarity between them at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Marshmallow Permissions not working for TargetVersion below 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232865/marshmallow-permissions-not-working-for-targetversion-below-23)

Comment: @R.Zagórski my question clearly does not ask for that, im asking why my permissions working on API >= M without requesting the permissions.

Comment: "target SDK for the app is android lollipop" -> that means it is below Manrshmallow, so the case is the same. Question is different but the case is the same and answers are suitable for you.

Comment: yes, it is possible. But that can give you a big problem. If the user deactivates some permission your app simple crushes because the permission is no longer available. The OS ask the user "This app was developed for a previous android version. disabling this permission can cause unexpected closing of the app" (ore some thing similar). In conclusion this is the normal behavior because the android version that you are using to compile you're app is before permissions needed to be confirmed by the user

Comment: @R.Zagórski not really, they are totally different questions and different meaning. if you read my question and the other question you would notice that he is asking how to  integrate M permissions in his app to check for something, while my question states that its working fine in Android M without requesting the permissions.

Comment: @Manuel_Rodrigues thank you for the explanation. that really explained it all.

Comment: I have posted an answer with a link where its all explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But that can give you a big problem. If the user deactivates some permission your app simple crushes because the permission is no longer available. The OS ask the user "This app was developed for a previous android version. disabling this permission can cause unexpected closing of the app" (ore some thing similar). In conclusion this is the normal behaviour because the android version that you are using to compile your app is before permissions needed to be confirmed by the user.

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

this link explains all you need to now about your question .

Comment: thanks, i have edited your question with the answer u provided in the comments to accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your app has `targetSdkVersion` below `23`, it will work  on M and above without asking any permissions (they will be asked during installation).

But if user will revoke any permission himself, app will crash. It was made by Google to get backwards compatibility with old applications that does not support new Permissions API.

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).
Here is quote from that page:

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target
>   SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your
>   manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the
>   app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install
>   the app at all.

Comment: so that is the reason, backwards compatibility. thanks.